# Visual Studio For Mac only uses csproj file, ignores launchSettings.json

Tags: settings, visual-studio-mac

We have a project that uses launchSettings.json to setup environment variables. When we open the project in the Visual Studio for Mac it ignores the launchSettings.json. When we add env. variables via the IDE (Properties > Configurations) it places them inside the .csproj file. (Inside the .csproj.user file if 'User-specific configuration' is selected.)

We need the Visual Studio to use the launchSetttings.json however there doesn't seem to be a way to make it. Even in the official documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/launch-settings?view=vsmac-2022) it is mentioned that it would use launchSettings.json however that doesn't seem to be the case.

Does anybody has a solution for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which sort of project are you using? launchSettings.json files are only supported with ASP.NET Core projects. Are you using some other project type?

Answer (score 2):

(Just posting this here from Matt Wards comment as I cannot mark the comment as the answer.)

As the comment suggests, Visual Studio for Mac seems to only use launchSettings.json for Asp.Net projects. I was working with a Console App.

Visual Studio for PC uses launchSettings.json for console applications too but not the Mac version.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try to change the properties of the file and how VS Studio treats it during build.

1. Right-click on `launchSettings.json` and choose `Properties`
2. Set the below properties as follows:

```
Build action -> Content
Copy to directory -> Copy if newer
```

See if this helps.

Comment: This doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Change the top line of your project file to the following:

`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`

(It was probably missing the `.Web` namespace)